# Fixing joining two datasets with same variables

Tags: join, error-handling

I want to join two datasets.
Datasets had same columns/ variables.
Dataset 1 (n11)

```
    caseid         v000  v005 age v021 v022 v023 v024 resi region v102 education pregnant v445 v501 v717 wealth   stra                                occupation
1      101  15  2  NP6 342191   5  101   10    1    1    2      1    2         1        0 2190    1    4      4 NPIR61FL$ssubreg=1, NPIR61FL$v025=2          2
2      101  19  2  NP6 342191   7  101   10    1    1    2      1    2         0        0 2300    1    4      3 NPIR61FL$ssubreg=1, NPIR61FL$v025=2          2
3      101  19  4  NP6 342191   2  101   10    1    1    2      1    2         1        0 2139    1    4      3 NPIR61FL$ssubreg=1, NPIR61FL$v025=2          2
4      101  21  4  NP6 342191   5  101   10    1    1    2      1    2         0        0 1855    1    4      2 NPIR61FL$ssubreg=1, NPIR61FL$v025=2          2
5      101  45  3  NP6 342191   5  101   10    1    1    2      1    2         0        0 2133    3    4      3 NPIR61FL$ssubreg=1, NPIR61FL$v025=2          2
6      101  47  2  NP6 342191   1  101   10    1    1    2      1    2         2        0 2022    1    4      4 NPIR61FL$ssubreg=1, NPIR61FL$v025=2          2
```

Dataset 2 (n16)

```
       caseid      v000 v005  age v021 v022 v023 v024 resi region v102 education pregnant v445 v501 v717 wealth           stra                       occupation
1      101   2  2  NP5 295061   6  101    1    1    1    2      1    2         0        0 2534    1    4      2 NPIR51FL$v024=1, NPIR51FL$v025=2          2
2      101   2  3  NP5 295061   1  101    1    1    1    2      1    2         2        0 2061    0    4      2 NPIR51FL$v024=1, NPIR51FL$v025=2          2
3      101   3  3  NP5 295061   1  101    1    1    1    2      1    2         2        0 2157    1    4      1 NPIR51FL$v024=1, NPIR51FL$v025=2          2
4      101   4  1  NP5 295061   4  101    1    1    1    2      1    2         0        0 2370    1    4      1 NPIR51FL$v024=1, NPIR51FL$v025=2          2
5      101   6  6  NP5 295061   2  101    1    1    1    2      1    2         3        0 2254    0    4      2 NPIR51FL$v024=1, NPIR51FL$v025=2          2
6      101   7  2  NP5 295061   2  101    1    1    1    2      1    2         2        0 2364    0    4      1 NPIR51FL$v024=1, NPIR51FL$v025=2          2
```

I used rbind function.
code was `d2 <-rbind(n11, n16)`

I found the following error. How can I fix this?

```
Error: Can't convert from <labelled<double>> to <labelled<double>> due to loss of precision.
* Locations: 5723, 5724, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729, 5730, 5731, 5732, 5733, 5734, 5735, 5736, 5...
Values are labelled in `` but not in ``.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution now.
We can use `full_join` function of `dplyr` package to solve this.

```
d2<- full_join(n11, n16)
```